# Getting a memory leak when signing aChar in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. I am having a problem where I am allocating memory without the `new` keyword. The memory leak starts from `UserInputCharArray[size - 1] = aChar`. I am assigning a character to a memory location which is not allocated using the `new` keyword.

Can anyone help me solve this issue to allocate memory using the `new` keyword?

Here is an image when I run:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Creating a function for high frequency letters by passing in our vowels and 
// a boolean for moving from lower-case vowels to upper-case vowels. 
void highestFreq(int a, int e, int i, int o, int u, bool isLow) {

    // Declaring variables.
    int maximumCount = 0;
    char mainChar;

    // Creating an array of five for the vowels.
    int arr[5];

    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = e;
    arr[2] = i;
    arr[3] = o;
    arr[4] = u;

    // Set counter to zero. 
    int counter = 0;

    // Looping through the vowels starting with value 1 -> 5.
    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++) {

        // Count when array is less than 
        if (arr[counter] < arr[x])

            counter = x;
    }

    // Looping through the vowels starting with value 0 -> 5
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

        // count plus one.
        if (arr[counter] == arr[x])

            maximumCount += 1;

    }

    // Checking with the vowels. 
    if (counter == 0)

        mainChar = 'a';

    else if (counter == 1)

        mainChar = 'e';

    else if (counter == 2)

        mainChar = 'i';

    else if (counter == 3)

        mainChar = 'o';

    else if (counter == 4)

        mainChar = 'u';



    // Moving from lower case letter to upper case letter. 
    if (!isLow)

     // Conversion happening here from lower-case to upper-case letters.
       mainChar = mainChar - 'a' + 'A';


    // If there are multiple high frequency letters then a message needs to be passed in there. 
    if (maximumCount > 1) {

        // checking to see if there are no lower case vowels .  
        if (isLow)

            // Display - if there is no lower case vowels or there is no 
            // upper case vowels. 
            cout << "There are no lower ";

        else

            // Otherwise - display there are no upper case vowels
            cout << "There are no upper ";
            cout << "case vowels" << "\n";

    }

    else {

        // Otherwise - display the highest frequency letters. 
        cout << "The highest frequency ";

        // Checking to see if there is any high frequency letters.  
        if (isLow)

            // Displaying lower case vowels
            cout << "lower ";

        else

            // Displaying upper case vowels
            cout << "upper ";

            // Display how many high frequency vowels are their. 
             cout << "case vowel is " << mainChar << " with a frequency of " << arr[counter] << "\n";

    }

}

int main() {

    // A char is being used -  for the user to still continue with the program. 
    char userInputProceed = 'y';

   // Looping begin for user to continue. 
    while (userInputProceed == 'Y' || userInputProceed == 'y') {

        // Declaration for the lower-case and upper-case vowels. 
        int low_a, low_e, low_i, low_o, low_u;
        int high_A, high_E, high_I, high_O, high_U;

        // Initializing the count of lower-case and upper-case vowels. 
        low_a = low_e = low_i = low_o = low_u = 0;
        high_A = high_E = high_I = high_O = high_U = 0;

        // Setting a size starting from one. 
        int size = 1;

        // Declaring a variable of type char.
        char aChar;

        // Declaring a size to be using the new operator.
        char *UserInputCharArray = new char[size];

        // Prompt the user to enter a string. 
        cout << "Enter a string: ";

        // Capturing userInput, one char at a time.
        aChar = cin.get();

        // A loop that will be taking values from the input stream and it will 
        // count the size of input.  \n
        while (aChar != 10) {

            // Count size of input.
            UserInputCharArray[size - 1] = aChar;

            // Getting each size and add one.
            size += 1;

            // Then get the char one at a time - once more. 
            aChar = cin.get();

        }

        // The loop process of the vowels.
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {

            aChar = *(UserInputCharArray + x);

            if (aChar - 'a' == 0)

                low_a += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'e' == 0)

                low_e += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'i' == 0)

                low_i += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'o' == 0)

                low_o += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'u' == 0)

                low_u += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'A' == 0)

                high_A += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'E' == 0)

                high_E += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'I' == 0)

               high_I += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'O' == 0)

                high_O += 1;

            else if (aChar - 'U' == 0)

                high_U += 1;

        }

        // Displaying lower-case vowels with their frequency and display - following with 
        // if the count of any vowel is zero then it will not be displayed. 
        if (low_a > 0 || low_e > 0 || low_i > 0 || low_o > 0 || low_u > 0) {

            cout << "The lower-case vowels which are present are: ";

            if (low_a > 0)

                cout << "a (" << low_a << ")";

            if (low_e > 0)

                cout << "e (" << low_e << ")";

            if (low_i > 0)

                cout << "i (" << low_i << ")";

            if (low_o > 0)

                cout << "o (" << low_o << ")";

            if (low_u > 0)

                cout << "u (" << low_u << ")";

            cout << endl;

        }

        // Displaying upper case vowels with their frequency and display - following with 
        // if the count of any vowel is zero then it will not be displayed. 
        if (high_A > 0 || high_E > 0 || high_I > 0 || high_O > 0 || high_U > 0) {

            cout << "The upper-case vowels which are present are: ";

            if (high_A > 0)

                cout << "A (" << high_A << ")";

            if (high_E > 0)

                cout << "E (" << high_E << ")";

            if (high_I > 0)

                cout << "I (" << high_I << ")";

            if (high_O > 0)

                cout << "O (" << high_O << ")";

            if (high_U > 0)

                cout << "U (" << high_U << ")";

            cout << endl;

        }

        // Calling out the high frequency letter function. 
        highestFreq(low_a, low_e, low_i, low_o, low_u, true);
        highestFreq(high_A, high_E, high_I, high_O, high_U, false);

        // Using the delete operator.
        delete[] UserInputCharArray;

        // Waiting for the user input if they want to continue with the program. 
        cout << "To continue enter y or Y, anything else will quit the program" << endl;

        // Getting the user input to continue with the program. 
        cin >> userInputProceed;

        // Wait for userInput until he/she quits.
        cin.get();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Updated Code**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

// ----- REFACTORED MY CODE.  ------


// Returning a lower case vowels. 
char LowVowel(int x) {

    switch(x) {
        case 0: 
            return 'a'; 
            break; 
        case 1: 
            return 'e'; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            return 'i'; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            return 'o'; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            return 'u'; 
            break; 

    }
}

// Returning a upper case vowels. 
char UpperVowel(int x) {

    switch (x) {
        case 0: 
            return 'A'; 
            break; 

        case 1: 
            return 'E'; 
            break; 
        case 2:
            return 'I'; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            return 'O'; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            return 'U'; 
            break; 
   }

}
// Initializing the array to be used for upper and lower cases frequency. 

void init(int arr[]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        arr[x] = 0; 
    }
}

int main() {

    // Declaring a variable of type char 
    char aChar; 

    // Allocation of memory to a character pointer as per the size of
    // the entered input.
    char *cPointer = new char; 

    // Store an array for the frequency of lower and upper vowels. 
    int arr[5]; 

    // counter and maximum to be stored for our maximum frequency. 
    int counter = 0, maximum; 

    // Prompting the user to enter a string. 
    cout << "Enter a string: "; 

    // Capturing userInput. 
    aChar = cin.get(); 

    while (aChar != '\n') {

        // increment counter. 
        counter++; 

        // then if enter key is pressed - stop entering data. 
        if (aChar == '\n')
            break; 

        // Storing the accepted char inside the pointer. 
        *(cPointer + counter) = aChar; 

        // Increase the counter. 
        aChar = cin.get(); 

    }

    // Initializing the arr array 
    init(arr); 

    // Looping until the end of inputted information. 
    for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) {

        // Checking the lower case vowels 
        // and even increase the counter

        if (*(cPointer + x) == 'a')
            arr[0]++; 
        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'e')
            arr[1]++; 
        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'i')
            arr[2]++; 
        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'o')
            arr[3]++; 
        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'u')
            arr[4]++; 
    }

    // Display lower case vowels results. 
    cout << "The lower-case vowels which are present are: \n ";


    // Looping.. 
    for (int x = 0;  x < 5; x++) {

        // find the maximum frequency. 
        maximum = arr[x]; 
        if (arr[x] > maximum) 
            maximum = x; 

        // then if the frequency value not zero then
        // display. 
        if (arr[x] != 0) {
           cout << LowVowel(x)  
            << " ( " << arr[x] << " )";
        }
    }
    // Display lower case vowels. 
    cout << "Lower case vowel " << LowVowel(maximum) 
    << " which appears most frequently = " << arr[maximum];

    // init the arr array . 
    init(arr); 

    // looping once again for the entered info. 
    for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) {

        // checking the upper case vowels 
        // and increasing the counter once again. 
        if (*(cPointer + x) == 'A')

            arr[0]++; 

        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'E')
            arr[1]++; 

        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'I')

            arr[2]++; 

        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'O')
            arr[3]++; 

        else if (*(cPointer + x) == 'U')
            arr[4]++; 
    }


    // Display upper case vowels. 
    cout << "Upper case vowels and its frequency" << endl;  

    // looping 
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

        // finding the maximum freq. 
        maximum = arr[x]; 
        if (arr[x] > maximum) 
            maximum = x; 

        // if the frequency value is not zero then display. 
        if (arr[x] != 0) {

            cout << "\n Vowel " << UpperVowel(x) << " occurred " << arr[x] << " times";

        }
     }

      cout << "Upper case vowel " << UpperVowel(maximum) << " which appears most frequently = " << arr[maximum];











}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

> I am assigning a character to a memory location which I am not even
>   allocated memory using the 'new' keyword.

Actually, you have allocated memory for that location... Specifically, you declare and allocate 1-char of data with:

```
int size = 1;
char *UserInputCharArray = new char[size];
```

So the pointer `UserInputCharArray` points to a valid block of memory of size `1`. The value at that memory address can be accessed by dereferencing the pointer with either:

```
*UserInputCharArray;
```

or

```
UserInputCharArray[0];  (or UserInputCharArray[size-1] as you used)
```

(the `[]` operator acts as a dereference.)

Both are equivalent. However, when using `[]`, you are limited to the single index `0`. Anything more (e.g. `1`) would invoke *Undefined Behavior* as an attempt to access memory outside the bounds of the block you allocated. (as you do in your loop beginning when `size = 2`)

**Why Not Use `string`?**

While you are free to manage the storage needs for `UserInputCharArray` your self with `new` and `delete`, you are far better served using the features of C++ (namely the `string` handling provides by `#include <string>`) that will provide automatic memory management for `UserInputCharArray`, e.g. you can `#include <string>` and change:

```
char *UserInputCharArray = new char[size];
```

to

```
string UserInputCharArray;
```

and then:

```
UserInputCharArray[size - 1] = aChar;
```

to

```
UserInputCharArray.push_back(aChar);
```

The memory will then also be freed when `UserInputCharArray` goes out of scope.

Note, you have additional logic errors with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @David .. I will try your snippet soon. I am working on a refactor version of my code,  I will post it tonight and let me know if that will work. Thank you!

Comment: Also note, you may not immediately crash when you access `UserInputCharArray[1];`, etc., because `new` will allocate a block of memory that is properly aligned and may contain more memory than just `1` char (though you cannot 'legally' use any of it) Why not use `string` instead of `char *` and let the container manage memory for you?

Comment: So, should I change my size to `size = 2`?  Please show me snippet prior  to my code above. thank you!

Comment: You should change your size to the maximum you anticipate `size += 1;` may reach and add a limit to your loop to protect your memory bounds, e.g. `while (size < MAXSIZE && aChar != 10) { ... }`

Comment: Better `#include <string>` and change `char *UserInputCharArray = new char[size];` to `string UserInputCharArray;` and then change `UserInputCharArray[size - 1] = aChar;` to `UserInputCharArray.push_back(aChar);`. `string` will automatically increase the size of `UserInputCharArray` as needed. (and will `free` it automatically when it goes out of scope). Otherwise you might as well write the code in C `:)`

Comment: In the comments section it's kind of hard to read.. Please update your answer above. Thank you :) .

Comment: OK, also go back through your logic, the `"Looping through the vowels starting with value"` loops make no sense.

Comment: You want to chat using stackoverflow ?  - So i can show you my refactored code

Comment: Sure, I'll have to figure out how to get there and open a channel for us. Damn, they keep updating these pages and now I don't have a simple "chat" button anymore. You can 'edit' your question and **add** your new code at the **end** of your current answer (don't delete your original code or the answers and comments will no longer make sense)

Comment: When clicking on "Add comment" in here you will see: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" Just click on "automatically move this discussion to chat"

Comment: Not for me, for whatever reason, all I get is another empty comment box -- I don't know why. I've used this site for 4 years and there has always been exactly what you describe. I think the problem is you don't have enough rep yet. Let me add to your rep and then we will see of chat is available again. (No joy -- I just get another comment box `:(`) Why don't you initiate the chat and I'll see if I get the invite. (I don't even see the widget that shows people currently chatting any more -- really strange)

Comment: To create a new room to chat: Please follow this instructions: There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper right corner of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.

Comment: There is a definite problem. Here is what I see [Screen Shot of My Browser Window Showing Footer](http://paste.opensuse.org/25226461). Looks like I'll have to post to Meta to find out what the problem is. Do you get a link? If I'm not seeing anything, then it must be a reputation < 20 issue. You should qualify now, but I can't explain the lack of an option to chat (I've done it many many times -- there is just no widget there now)

Comment: check my updated code please. Also, keep in mind I am using infinite loop but I want to make a good habit to NOT use global variables
,labels or go-to statements
infinite loops, examples include:
for(;;)
while(1)
while(true)
do{//code}while(1);
and even no break statements to exit loops.

Comment: ByTheWay: Your code above gave me some errors with: `candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'int'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
error: cannot delete expression of type 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
       delete[] UserInputCharArray;`

Comment: Everything O-K, @David?

Comment: Yes, sorry, had a phone call. Your problem is coming from the logic being somewhat convoluted. What you should do is think about making classification easy -- using a frequency array for each lower and upper case vowels. Then simply determine which vowel of each case occurred the most frequently and the index (which you can relate to the character) to be able to identify what occurred the most frequent and how many times it occurred. Here is a link to get you going (note: it will choose the 1st vowel if there is a tie for most frequent) [example](http://paste.opensuse.org/86876722)

Comment: Sure. Last advise I would have for you would be "don't try and code it all at once". For example, instead of trying to code both upper/lower case handling at once, instead, take one case and implement that first. Once you have it all working, then you can extend it to the other case -- but make sure you have the simple case working first -- then build outwards. That applies no matter what you are trying to model. The smaller the bites, the less chance there is of choking. Good luck with your coding. After sufficient time, don't forget to select an answer to your question.